# symfony moving from several bundles (3.4) to AppBundle (4.0)

Tags: symfony, bundle, upgrade

So I'm finally taking this bull by the horns and moving from 3.4 to 4.x and one of the undocumented (?) steps is that previously, all my code was supposed to live in separate bundles per function on the site (at least this was recommended).

Now, suddenly all my code is expected to live inside one bundle (src) and I understand some already had this approach previously, using only the AppBundle with no subdirectories. Obviously this will mess things up when moving from several bundles into one. For one thing, there are several files called DefaultController.php (one per bundle, as I have a LogBundle, a FinanceBundle, a UserBundle etc.

Is there a nice guide to how this move is best made, what paths need to be changed where etc.? Seems like the symfony guys considered this a small little change and no reason to provide a step-by-step, I find it quite annoying  or perhaps I'm just stupid

According to this guide https://symfonycasts.com/blog/AppBundle no code changes are necessary, but my app breaks all over the place when moving files into another directory structure, I suspect routes to templates will need modification, routes to controllers etc.

It also seems that every single Entity relationship breaks when the path to the entity's php file changes...

Rewireing this is a major job, I don't understand why this isn't adressed anywhere?

And while the site referenced above mentions that up to 4.0 your own code resided in several bundles, it seemes that the sample code from sensiolabs silently changed from ACME/DemoBundle to AppBundle between versions 2.4 (https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/2.4/src) and 2.5 (https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/2.5/src) without any instruction to change your own directory structure to mimic that back then (https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/upgrading.html).

So confused

Currently my directory structure looks like this

[image]

Comment: Symfony suggests organising code inside src folder into bundles. Bundle should have defined folder structure (controllers, services etc.). Was your original code organised in that way?
You can either tweak autoloading in composer.json or search&replace changes namespaces

Comment: If you are moving to 4.x then you don't even have an AppBundle anymore.  S4 moves you toward a bundle-less application approach.  Everything ends up being under the App namespace.  You don't actually have to do this.  Multiple bundles will still work just fine but as you have noticed the docs all assume no application bundles.  Transiting can be a pain but most of us did it years ago.  All you can really do is bite the bullet start copy/pasting/refactoring.  You might even consider jumping directly to 5.4 or even 6.x.

Comment: And I would not suggest trying to do this in place.  Start with a new app and go from there.  That will also flag any third party bundles that are not longer supported.  Which is where the real fun of upgrading is.

Comment: Would you rename things to keep a certain structure then, say for instance Poslog-defaultController, ExtraOpening-defaultController etc? It seems this is a step back into the good old days of non-OO structures where all script files were in one messy folder =) Or would you use subfolders to keep things arranged?

Comment: To a certain extent it depends on how many controllers and what they are for but I would probably add a folder under controller for each bundle so `App\Controller\Poslog\DefaultController` .  The same approach can be used for entities, forms, templates etc.  And remember that if you feel the bundles are useful then you can always just keep them.  `Recommended` does not mean mandatory.